# Find suid and gid files under root

Tags: unix, find, command

I’m looking for `find` command arguments to find all files under the `/` that have setuid and setgid privileges. I have `find / ???` so far.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

setuid **or** setgid ([GNU findutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/)):

```
find / -perm /6000
```

setuid **or** setgid (POSIX):

```
find / -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000
```

setuid **and** setgid:

```
find / -perm -6000
```

Comment: Note, on OSX, I had an error "illegal mode string" and had to use the POSIX version to make it work.

Comment: You may want to add `-type f` (as the OP asks) otherwise directories with setuid/setgid (entirely different meaning) will show up.

Answer (score 9):

```
find / \( -perm -u+s -o -perm -g+s \) -type f
```

Comment: Does this miss files with *both* setuid and setgid?

Comment: No, the `-o` means `or`.

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -perm -u=s  -g=s -type f 2>/dev/null
```

> the following command you can enumerate all binaries having SUID permission.